# How to force Android to install app with date or security problem?

Tags: installation, apk

I want to install an app on my new Samsung phone. The app was already working on my old Samsung phone. It seems that it cannot be installed due to security reasons.

I get the following errors with different versions of this app:

- `Failure [-3000: INSTALL_FAILED_REJECTED_BY_DATE]`
- `Failure [-3003: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_CERTIFICATION]`

How can I force Android to install this App?

Device model: Galaxy S21 FE,
Android version 12,
App: Ubridge Plug-in1 for SAMSUNG.

Comment: Could you mention the device model, Android version, and the app you're trying to install? Browsing the AOSP source code, this doesn't look like a standard error code but was added by Samsung (ref: [XDA Forum - Samsung Gear 360 Manager app](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/mod-port-samsung-gear-360-manager-for-all-devices-updated-21-jan-21-v1-4-00-4-fw.3400383/post-84522007))

Comment: Dear Andrew, thanks for your reply. @andrew-t.

Device model: Galaxy S21 FE.
Android version 12.
app: Ubridge Plug-in1 for SAMSUNG.